# USB detection using jQuery and HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, usb, port, drivers

I am trying to crate real time centralized web-app, where i need to read hardware attached to client, so they can use them directly with any manual inventions.

e.g. if someone attach an scanner or finger reader to his system, my application detect those devices and popup to the client,

I want to do this using html5 and jquery
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not possible unless using nodejs, you need a server side language to detect these hardware changes.

Comment: If websites were allowed to access our hardware with just javascript, think of the mess we would be going through.

Comment: I want to know about, is their any method like we are using getUsermedia to detect & use web-cam & microphones

Comment: @geohut, can you please elaborate hoe to use node.js for my use

Comment: Im making it an answer. @AmitSingh

Comment: @Geohut Since when is Node server-side? :-)

Comment: Always since it was made @TylerH

Comment: @Geohut It's JavaScript; it runs in the browser.

Comment: Nodejs is a server side language it is built on chromium it runs on the server it runs its own web server https://nodejs.org/ it also can be used to develop applications on a computer to run browser like functions and can be used via command line @TylerH comments aren't a place for such a discussion anyways.

Comment: @Geohut, I want to integrate this module t my one of the web-application, So how can i integrate it with my application, since node run with its own browser

Comment: What you want is impossible...

Answer (score 0):

Sure you would need to run a nodejs server on the box. There are also a few modules out there. I'm assuming these devices are plugged in with USB which then you will need a module wrapper for libusb one of the most popular used usb detection drivers. https://github.com/schakko/node-usb that is a common one. Then have a web socket open on the html5 jquery and listen from the nodejs server when something is plugged in.

Comment: I want to run the application through web browser..  @geohut, can you give explanation over any of the examples, how it works, & again it uses C header files.

Comment: That is impossible to run it through web browser alone.

Comment: That why, I need a jquery function

Comment: Jquery will not allow it either.. Like I said it's impossible using javascript/html